# how to loop through strings-arrays and add to realm database?

Tags: android, arrays, database, loops, realm

I have strings-arrays like this.

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="names">
        <item>foo/item>
        <item>bar</item>
        <item>moo</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="majors">
        <item>E.P</item>
        <item>M.P</item>
        <item>E.P</item>
    </string-array>
    <integer-array name="years">
        <item>1968</item>
        <item>1993</item>
        <item>1995</item>
    </integer-array>
</resources>
```

And an Student class for RealmObject.

```
public class Student extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String major;
    private Short year;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMajor() {
        return major;
    }

    public void setMajor(String major) {
        this.major = major;
    }

    public Short getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(Short year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

I would like to loop through each string-arrays and put each names, majors and years to realm Object(Student).realm.commitTransaction() insert data to one object.I want to insert data as three students to realm database.How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,

```
String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);
        String[] majors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.majors);
        String[] years = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.years);
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
               for(int i=0; i<names.size; i++) {
                   String name = names[i];
                   String major = majors[i];
                   String year = years[i];
                   short yearValue = Short.valueOf(year);

                   Student student = new Student();
                   student.setId(i);
                   student.setName(name);
                   student.setYear(yearValue);

                   realm.insertOrUpdate(student);
             }
        });
```